# Can't align css elements

Tags: css

I am trying to code a website using CSS. My header looks like this below. It is consisted of two child divs - logo and topright. Whenever I minimize the width of the screen, topright gets shunted downwards onto the next row. The two divs are floated left and right respectively, and should share the same row. However, I do not want topright to be shunted to the next row. How can I fix this?

```
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
  <h1><a href="index.html">Logo</a></h1>
</div>
<div id="topright">
<div id="phone">
  <p>here</p>
  <h6><a href="#">Learn about out services</a></h6> </div>
<div id="ssl">  

     <img src="images/ssl.png" width="150" height="39" align="right" />

    </div>

</div>
```

My css code is

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    }
#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: block;

    }   

#logo h1 {
    text-indent: -2000px;
    background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;

    }
#logo h1 a {
    display:block;
    width: 381px;
    height: 97px;
    }
#topright {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
display: block;
}
#phone {
    float: left;
    background:url(images/phone.png) no-repeat right;
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    text-align:right;

    }
#phone p {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
#phone h6 {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color:#6F694F;
    }
#ssl {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is because you are using px instead of %. Pixels will always try to retain their size and can make it look glitchy. Use percentages instead.

Comment: of course, if that's not the case then can you please post a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: Hello, I am using %, the only place i use px is for the logo

Comment: How do you want it aligned? I may know a solution if you simply want the logo not to move. Also, can you post more code? Right now, the #topright has no content in it and is not even appearing.

Comment: I would like to make the header responsive so now when I make the screen smaller the whole right side jumps in the next line. So I would like to avoid this. If it jumps down it messes up my slider. thanks.

Comment: so you want the logo to go down to the next line? The code you posted looks like this from my point of view: http://jsfiddle.net/gwpz2uL1/

Really sorry, but it's still pretty unclear what you want.

Comment: @Parlanchina - it's not really clear what you want to achieve.

1) When you talk about "make the screen smaller" and / or "minimize the window"... what do you mean? Do you mean when you make the window narrower (ie. reduce the window width)? Or shorter (ie. reduce the window height)? Or both at the same time?

2) When you make the window narrower / shorter / both (see Q1 above), what do you then want to happen?

Comment: I would like to keep the logo on the left and just make all align horizontally in one line when you view the header with a smaller screen.
By smaller window I mean: this is when you see the page with a smaller screen. So when I reduce the window width, the right area goes in the next line instead of being horizontally aligned with the logo.

Comment: It seems like that's already happening.

Comment: is it possible to post a link here and show what I mean and trying to do?

Comment: @parlanchina yeah, just paste the link and it automatically converts it.

Comment: Thanks DaemonOfTheWes.
Here it is http://www.kaniamea.com/fern/ When you open the page and make the window smaller (decrease the width) the top header jumps down in the green area. This also happens to third tour box. I wonder if I do something wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Ok - I see what you mean. The problem was that the code you gave in the original problem didn't have anything in logo or topright, so we couldn't even see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `min-width: 1000px` into `logo`'s css. This ensures that there is always 1000px, however hidden, that the `topright` div can fit inside even if it is off the screen.

Comment: Thanks DaemonOfTheWest! This really helped!